# Cloudflare and .DE domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cloudflare

It's been a week since I'm having trouble with switching my .DE domain to work through Cloudflare. After registering at Cloudflare I got two dns servers

```
gail.ns.cloudflare.com 
mark.ns.cloudflare.com
```

But my hoster (I got hosting and domains on the same account) refused to change my existing DNS servers to the Cloudflare ones. After a long conversation, the hoster changed the servers to

```
alice.ns.cloudflare.com 
ian.ns.cloudflare.com
```

saying that it's not possibile to change them again to gail and mark. 
The hoster mostly replies that Cloudflare has no proper DNS records on their servers.

Can you explain, what is the root of such rescrictions ? 
Is there any special legal requirement for .DE domains?

**UPDATE**

After a few more days of talking, the issue was resolved. 
As I was told by the Cloudflare support, some European registrars require valid records to be present *before* you can change the DNS server for your domain. This is the case with the .DE domain. And that's where it went wrong when I first created my Cloudflare account. The cloudflare supported fixed it, everything is working fine now.

**@HBruijn** provided the link for [Nameserver Predelegation Check for .DE domains](https://www.denic.de/service/tools/nast/), which was really helpful, because I had to call DENIC at first, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can glance the German registry [DENIC](https://www.denic.de/)  will verify if the name servers for a domain are configured correctly and whether the zone is in accordance with the DENIC guidelines before allowing registration and name server changes.

You can test the validity of your name-server(s) with their NAST tool http://nast.denic.de/ where you can also find the technical requirements (in [German](https://www.denic.de/fileadmin/public/documentation/DENIC-23p.pdf) and [English](https://www.denic.de/fileadmin/public/documentation/DENIC-23p_EN.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of such limitation. It rather sounds like your host is the one enforcing such limitation.

To verify if cloudfare has your DNS records configured accordingly you can use the following command in cmd.

```
nslookup <my-domain> <target-dns-server>
```

For example:

```
nslookup mydomain.de gail.ns.cloudflare.com
nslookup www.mydomain.de mark.ns.cloudflare.com
```

Comment: I've never heard about it either XD. Both nslookup mydomain.de alice.ns.cloudflare.com and nslookup mydomain.de gail.ns.cloudflare.com work. But the tool http://nast.denic.de/ only works with alice.... why? ....